# kafka kraft + exception when query topic __cluster_metadata-0

Tags: apache-kafka

We have 3 brokers production Kafka machines ,

each Kafka machine include dedicated `server.properties` for Kafka broker and `server.properties` for controller ,

brokers & controllers are installed on `RHEL 8.X` machines ,

Broker version - version 3.6 with Kraft mode

Kafka Replication factor is 3.

Brokers IDS are

```
101
102
103
```

and controllers ids are

```
1
2
3
```

brokers services and controllers services are up and running

here few details from our cluster

regarding to `kafka-metadata-quorum` , The following example prints out the status of the cluster:

```
kafka-metadata-quorum.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 describe --status

ClusterId:              jeKjshGSFegdWdjej_kKjwhb
LeaderId:               201
LeaderEpoch:            1671
HighWatermark:          1797393
MaxFollowerLag:         0
MaxFollowerLagTimeMs:   0
CurrentVoters:          [201,202,203]
CurrentObservers:       [101,102,103]
```

diverse output for –replication option,

```
kafka-metadata-quorum.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 describe --replication
NodeId  LogEndOffset    Lag     LastFetchTimestamp      LastCaughtUpTimestamp   Status
1      1793597         0       1704281102997           1704281102997           Leader
2      1797074         0       1704282323340           1704282323340           Follower
3      1793597         0       1704281102954           1704281102954           Follower
101    1793597         0       1704281102929           1704281102929           Observer
102    1793597         0       1704281102948           1704281102948           Observer
103    1793597         0       1704281102953           1704281102953           Observer
```

the problem start when we want to get data from the `kafka-metadata-shell` utility , its another approach to explore the log files

`kafka-metadata-shell.sh --snapshot /kafka/data/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000001684765365.log`

```
[2024-01-03 11:39:15,787] ERROR Encountered shell fault: Error loading metadata log record from offset 16276800 (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.LoggingFaultHandler)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.image.TopicDelta.replay(TopicDelta.java:76)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.TopicsDelta.replay(TopicsDelta.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.MetadataDelta.replay(MetadataDelta.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.MetadataDelta.replay(MetadataDelta.java:202)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataBatchLoader.replay(MetadataBatchLoader.java:257)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataBatchLoader.loadBatch(MetadataBatchLoader.java:135)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader.lambda$handleCommit$1(MetadataLoader.java:361)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventContext.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.handleEvents(KafkaEventQueue.java:210)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:181)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[2024-01-03 11:39:15,787] ERROR Encountered shell fault: Error generating new metadata image from metadata delta between offset 1627679 and 1627680 (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.LoggingFaultHandler)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.image.TopicDelta.apply(TopicDelta.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.TopicsDelta.apply(TopicsDelta.java:145)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.MetadataDelta.apply(MetadataDelta.java:381)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataBatchLoader.applyDeltaAndUpdate(MetadataBatchLoader.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataBatchLoader.maybeFlushBatches(MetadataBatchLoader.java:208)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader.lambda$handleCommit$1(MetadataLoader.java:365)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventContext.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.handleEvents(KafkaEventQueue.java:210)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:181)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[2024-01-03 11:39:15,787] ERROR Encountered shell fault: Error loading metadata log record from offset 16276820 (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.LoggingFaultHandler)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.image.TopicDelta.replay(TopicDelta.java:76)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.TopicsDelta.replay(TopicsDelta.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.MetadataDelta.replay(MetadataDelta.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.MetadataDelta.replay(MetadataDelta.java:202)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataBatchLoader.replay(MetadataBatchLoader.java:257)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataBatchLoader.loadBatch(MetadataBatchLoader.java:135)
        at org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader.lambda$handleCommit$1(MetadataLoader.java:361)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventContext.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.handleEvents(KafkaEventQueue.java:210)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:181)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

when **expected** data results should be like the following example

```
kafka-metadata-shell.sh --snapshot /data/kafka/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000001684765365.log
>> ls /
brokers  features  local  metadataQuorum  topicIds  topics
```

about the exceptions as

```
ERROR Encountered shell fault: Error loading metadata log record from offset 16276820 (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.LoggingFaultHandler)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

is that above exception indicate on corrupted `__cluster_metadata-0` , or maybe indicate on other controller problem ?